# Computer stopped working when multiple cores enabled

Tags: cpu, freeze, hardware-failure, intel-core-i7

My computer started freezing while booting Windows 7 or linux. I recently discovered that I can boot only when a single core is enabled in the BIOS. I didn't add/remove hardware or update BIOS. No heating problems, no overclocking. Computer worked fine for almost a year with Windows 7. What do you think is broken?

Does this mean the CPU is broken? Is there any chance motherboard or other component is broken? How can I tell the source of the problem for sure?

- CPU: Intel i7-2600k
- Motherboard: asus P8P67-M rev 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Without having different sets of hardware (main board, cpu, ram) and exchanging it will be hard to find the defect piece of hardware. It may worth giving a BIOS reset/update a try. Can you try to install a clean Windows or Linux distribution with enabled multi-core?

Comment: I tried installing linux but it also freezes. Bios is updated after the event.